# How to correctly organize Tensorflow model layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Hellow world!
We are writing our own AI and we struggle to create correct model layer.
What we have to input in our neural network is a `list` that contains n `lists` with m `tuples`

```
e.x. list = numpy.array([ [[1,2,4],[5,6,8]] , [[5,6,0],[7,2,4]] ])
```

What we expect to get as a result is either 0 or 1 ( it makes sense trust me )

This is what we have for now:

```
tpl = 3 # because we have tuples
nl = 2 # number of lists we have
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
# this should be entry layer that understands our list
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(nl * tpl , input_shape=(nl, tpl), activation='relu'),

#hidden layers..
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, input_shape=(nl, tpl), activation='sigmoid'),

#our output layer with 2 nodes that one should contain 0, other 1, because we have 2 labels ( 0 and 1 )
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, input_shape=(0, 1), activation='softmax')
        ])
```

But we get the error below:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [56,2,2] vs. [56,1]
     [[node huber_loss/Sub (defined at <ipython-input-25-08eb2e0b395e>:53) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_45699]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

If we summarize our model, it gives, the following structure:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 2, 6)              24        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 2, 64)             448       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 2, 2)              130       
=================================================================
```

Finally,

What we have understood is that our provided data is not compatible with the last layer, so how do we convert the last layer to => shape **(None, 2)** or what is the right way to work this error out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Flatten()` or `GlobalAveragePooling1D` before your output layer. Full example:

```
import numpy
import tensorflow as tf

list = numpy.array([[[1., 2., 4.], [5., 6., 8.]], [[5., 6., 0.], [7., 2., 4.]]])

tpl = 3  
nl = 2   
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(nl * tpl, input_shape=(nl, tpl), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, input_shape=(nl, tpl), activation='sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, input_shape=(0, 1), activation='softmax')
])

model.build(input_shape=(nl, tpl))

model(list)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.41599566, 0.58400434],
       [0.41397247, 0.58602756]], dtype=float32)>
```

You won't get only 0 and 1 though, you'll get probabilities per class. Also you should shadow the built in keyword `list`.

```
Model: "sequential_4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 2, 6)              24        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_13 (Dense)             (None, 2, 64)             448       
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling1d (Gl (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_14 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 130       
=================================================================
Total params: 602
Trainable params: 602
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```